# Visual Studio 2017: Default language other than en-US

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, visual-studio-2017

This problem is around for quite a while. I expected it to be fixed in VS 2017, but it wasn't. Here is a way to reproduce it.

1. Open VS2017 (or VS2015) and create a new UWP project.
2. In the Package Manifest (Package.appxmanifest) change default language from `en-US` to `en`.
3. In Assembly Information you can either leave Neutral Language as `None`, or set it to `English`  (this adds line `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]` to AssemblyInfo.cs).
4. In Solution Explorer select 'Assets' folder and create subfolder `en` (Right click - Add - New Folder - type `en`). Copy a .png file (e.g. `StoreLogo.png`) to the newly created subfolder. (Actually my real app supports several languages, but one language is enough to demonstrate the issue.)

That's it! Build the project and you'll get a message:

```
MakePRI : warning 0xdef00522: Resources found for language(s) 'en'
but no resources found for default language(s): 'en-US'.
Change the default language or qualify resources with the default language.
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231899
```

Unfortunately, the site quoted in the message doesn't bring light to the problem.

I've noticed that generated priconfig.xml contains the following section:

```
<index root="\" startIndexAt="obj\x86\Debug\resources.en-us.resfiles">
    <default>
      <qualifier name="Language" value="en-us" />
      <qualifier name="Contrast" value="standard" />
      <qualifier name="Scale" value="200" />
      <qualifier name="HomeRegion" value="001" />
      <qualifier name="TargetSize" value="256" />
      <qualifier name="LayoutDirection" value="LTR" />
      <qualifier name="DXFeatureLevel" value="DX9" />
      <qualifier name="Configuration" value="" />
      <qualifier name="AlternateForm" value="" />
      <qualifier name="Platform" value="UAP" />
    </default>

    <indexer-config type="RESW" convertDotsToSlashes="true" />
    <indexer-config type="RESJSON" />
    <indexer-config type="RESFILES" qualifierDelimiter="." />
  </index>
```

However I have no idea where 'en-us' comes from.

The Store bundle is created allright with no `en-us` in the AppxBundleManifest.xml.  Running app with an unsupported language is also OK, it uses English (`en`). The app passes certification with Microsoft store.

Still, I would prefer to get rid of this message. Any ideas?

Comment: If you think this is a bug in VS 2017 you should report it using the small icon in upper right corner next to the Quick Launch text field.

Comment: Marian Dolinsky:  I reported the issue to Microsoft, however it looks too obvious for a VS bug. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me too. Happens if you set everything to "fr" or "en-GB" too. I have known other VS bugs in the past that assumed a default language of "en-US" so this isn't beyond the limits of possibility. May be a UWP tooling issue if not VS itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. This is a known issue in VS/MSBuild. We are syncing with the related team on this issue. The warning is coming from the fact that .NET Core Framework binaries have "en-US" as a default language.

> Still, I would prefer to get rid of this message. Any ideas?

Temporarily, the only possible workaround is to declare default language "en-US". But as you've known, this warning won't break your dev progress, you can ignore it and move forward. ;)